# Validation using NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` with combination of `username & password`, how can i validate it using objective C?

*For Ex:*

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dictionary setObject:@"A" forKey:@"A"];
[dictionary setObject:@"B" forKey:@"B"];
[dictionary setObject:@"C" forKey:@"C"];
```

How can i validate for username & password as key value pairs.

Comment: Here key is username?

Comment: @krishna Skw first of all you said me which kind of username validation you have to do? means like email validation ?

Comment: Krishna check my ans and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways:

**In one line:**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"username1", @"pass1",
         @"username2", @"pass2",
         @"username3", @"pass3",
         @"username4", @"pass4", nil];
```

Another way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"username1" forKey:@"pass1"];
[dict setObject:@"username2" forKey:@"pass2"];
// so on ...
```

Another using `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *username = @[@"username1", @"username2", @"username3", @"username4"];
NSArray *passwords = @[@"pass1", @"pass2", @"pass3", @"pass4"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:username forKeys:passwords];

// see output
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
// separately
NSLog(@"Usernames: %@", [dict allValues]);
NSLog(@"Passwords: %@", [dict allKeys]);
```

You can validate by extracting separate keys and values accordingly or using blocks `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock`:

```
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

    // place your validation code here 
    NSLog(@"There are %@ %@'s in stock", obj, key);
}];
```

[Complete source](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary).

Answer (score 0):

To easily validate the content of the dictionary you can just access the key and validate the value.

## Example:

```
// this assumes that the key is the username and the value is the password
NSDictionary *credential = @{@"username1":@"pass1",@"username2":@"pass2"/* , ..and so on */};

NSString *username = @"<user_input_or_whatever>";

NSString *passwordInput = @"<user_input_or_whatever>";

NSString *password = credential[username];

// if password is nil because username is not present the the condition below fails.
if([password isEqualToString:passwordInput]){
   // both password and username matched
}
else{
  // username or password didn't matched
}
```